# "react-otp-input" Library - Display information in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, format, react-typescript, react-otp-input

Here is the code I use "react-otp-input" library:

```
<OtpInput
                      value={otpCode}
                      onChange={setOtpCode}
                      numInputs={6}
                      inputType="tel"
                      renderSeparator={
                        <span
                          style={{
                            fontSize: "7px",
                            marginLeft: "5px",
                            marginRight: "5px",
                          }}
                        >
                          {" "}
                        </span>
                      }
                      renderInput={(props) => <input {...props} />}
                      inputStyle={{
                        width: "30px",
                        marginBottom: "10px",
                        height: "30px",
                        borderTop: "none",
                        borderLeft: "none",
                        borderRight: "none",
                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                        outline: "none",
                      }}
                    />
```

What I want is that when I go to the website by phone and enter otp in the input box above, the numeric keypad will stay the same, not switch to the alphanumeric keyboard after each input, and the character displayed in the input box is * (******), now because of "inputType="tel"" the keyboard will be preserved, but the numbers I enter are still in numeric form, not as * as I want, please point me to the solution decided, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.